# Opening URI in overlay, not main page

Tags: overlay

On my page, overlays are loaded by inserting their content with jQuery and then fading in.

What I want to do is this:

When you click to open an overlay, an URI is loaded (e.g. news/12, where news is the category and 12 is the id of the item to load).
Except, instead of loading it in body, it should be loaded in the overlay.

In other words, I want to achieve something like on facebook, where you open an overlay, the url changes, but the main page stays the same.

I'm guessing you need ajax for this, but I have no idea whatsoever how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "overlay"? if you're just talking about dialogs, use boxy or something similar : http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/

Comment: basically dialogs, yeah, but I've already designed my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the new `history.pushState(...)` and `history.popState(...)` browser API.
This SO post might help you out: [Change the URL in the browser without loading the new page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136458/how-do-i-with-javascript-change-the-url-in-the-browser-without-loading-the-new)

Comment: The only problem is, when I push back or forward, the page doesn't change.
And one more problem: I'm having trouble fetching the base url to append the new url to.

Comment: Okay, so I think the problem is that when doing pushState, the URI is changed, but the active URL isn't. So when I call pushState in javascript, it acts on the active URL, which isn't always the same.

Comment: You probably want to register `popstate` event handler, or something. I'm not sure. Try more googling, and reading this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Yes,
window.onpopstate = function() {
    location.href = location.pathname;
};
did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Boxy. See http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/tests.html#

AJAX example:

```
<a href='#' onclick='Boxy.load("test-1.html");'>Test 1</a>
```

See this question: [Ajax - How to change URL by content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867205/ajax-how-to-change-url-by-content)

Comment: I've already designed my own, so I'd rather continue with this than throw it all away :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it thanks to Lethargy's answer.

`.pushState()` is exactly what I need to have the URL reflect the contents of the overlay that is dynamically created with jQuery.

With some tweaking around and debugging I managed to get it all working.

Now my overlays (or popups, dialogs, whatever) are search engine ready, and the url is copy-pastable for users :)