# Does Internet Explorer support pushState and replaceState?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, pushstate

Does anybody know if Internet Explorer supports the `history.pushState()` and `history.replaceState()` methods for [manipulating browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)? Considering these are just being implemented in Firefox 4, I'm not holding my breath, but does anybody know if they're coming in IE9?

Comment: Depressing indeed if IE9 does not add this.

Comment: For what it's worth [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js) provides the same HTML5 API while gracefully degrading any browser that doesn't support it (including support for data and titles, and replaceState functionality). Using that would mean you wouldn't have to change your code for the IE9 changes.

Comment: On the other hand, some argue against falling back to hashes. http://danwebb.net/2011/5/28/it-is-about-the-hashbangs

Comment: @balupton, I followed your instructions on downloading and installing `history.js` but after I refreshed my page, errors like `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` are on my console, about 23 of them. What did I do wrong? Please help!

Comment: @CHiRiLo: You need to include a reference to [jQuery](http://jquery.com). This is a javascript library from Google that is widely used, and will make your life a lot easier when working with javascript in your web sites.

Comment: Google isn't the primary developer for jQuery (it might have contributed); it does host it on its CDN though.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Probably the best site for browser compatibility information is [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/). Here's the section on [history](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history).

Summary - **IE9: no**, **IE10: yes** (as of platform preview 3)

The first Release Candidate of IE9 (released 10th Feb 2011) does not support history.pushState or history.replaceState. Generally no new features are added after a product gets to RC stage so it is very unlikely that the final IE9 will support these methods.

Microsoft have a good [overview for developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705) of the features IE9 does have.

Update: **Internet Explorer 9 was launched** (on 14th March 2011) and definitely **does not support `history.pushState()` or `history.replaceState()`.**

Update 2: The current platform preview of [IE10 still does not support pushState / replaceState](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ukmsdn/archive/2011/06/29/ie10-platform-preview-2-released.aspx).

Update 3: Platform Preview 3 of IE10 **supports the history API!** [Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920758%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: As of today, IE10 history has a **bug** making it useless, the popstate event does not fire. Details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698299/internet-explorer-10-and-popstate-not-binding/15809188#15809188

Answer (score 17):

IE9 doesn't support it.

You can however use a work around using a Polyfill to get the functionality - History.js https://github.com/browserstate/history.js.

Modernizr do a good job listing HTML 5 Polyfills here https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills.

**The caveat is that it will add a query string to your URL in browsers that only support HTML 4 features.**

Comment: as of the comments in the above question, popstate does not fire in IE10

Comment: History.js is a good solution if you must support IE 9 or below, but it's 23KB, minified. That's a lot for just supporting a few methods.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 10 introduces support for the History interface of the HTML5 draft specification, which includes methods that enable you to manage a site's history stack and URL.

The original link:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920758(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Btw you can get such error in reason of absolute path in pushState(). When i set relative path error was disappeared.