# Which browsers support the HTML5 History API?

Tags: html, browser, compatibility, pushstate

Can someone point me to a compatibility chart for browsers that support/don't support the HTML5 History API?

Spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html
Tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: IE10 does support it as per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4968481/1129108

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This might help : http://caniuse.com/#search=history

Comment: So, WebKit-based browsers and Firefox 4. Thanks.

Comment: Great link, thanks. History API sadly not available in early Android and iPhone browsers.

Answer (score 7):

All the modern browsers now do it, except IE (even IE10 no word yet) - though they all implement it differently. You can read about the differences with their implementations here https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/The-State-of-the-HTML5-History-API

Comment: IE10 actually does support it!