# How does this site change the site location?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, location

> http://www.beatport.com

How are they doing that?

They are changing the url in the browser without using hash like `#` characters and stuff like that. And without refreshing, just ajax :|

The URLs look like normal URLs,
you can go from the homepage directly to
http://www.beatport.com/genre/psy-trance/13
without page refresh

Comment: It ends up as http://www.beatport.com/#genre/psy-trance/13 (YES the # is in there) after it loads. The same happens with the other links on the page. when hovering over them the # is not shown but after the link is clicked/loaded the # is in the location.

Comment: it's not there!!1 :D all links are normal, no `#` and the urls too.. Is this black magic or something?

Comment: It depends on whether your browser supports HTML5 History or not. Try with some old IE or FF 3.6> to see the hashes.

Comment: Im using Opera. What other browsers support html5 history?

Comment: It adds a # in the url in IE10 it doesn't on FF4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612598/which-browsers-support-the-html5-history-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the History API.

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/history.html
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: this is sick... now there's no reason not to use ajax for everything

Comment: Of course there is. It just changes the location url. It won't load the new page for you. You still need to use Ajax to get the new content and append it to the page. It just solves the problem with back buttons on AJAX websites.

Comment: yea, but that was the only problem with ajax. now it's gone so you can use ajax to get new pages. I'm going to hook on live(click) all my links and replace all body elements with the ones from the target page :)

Comment: Feel free if you don't need to support iE

Answer (score 1):

They're probably leveraging the [HTML 5 History API](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/history.html).

Answer (score 0):

Correcting my previous answer, see [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page). See the second answer.

Comment: That would generate a JS refresh.