# How is pjax working?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I just discovered [pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com/) and I find it completly awesome. If I understand it correctly, it's AJAX, but without its problems (fully degradable, the URL and the title of the page is changing when using it, compatible with search bots...).

But I am very curious as how it's working ? How can we change the URL in the browser, without the page to change... I read somewhere you need Firefox 4, is that a new "web" feature then ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's just a wrapper around "$.ajax()".  It uses the new "pushState" and "replaceState" methods to manipulate the history.

Also [see this SO question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722815/does-internet-explorer-support-pushstate-and-replacestate), and notably the link to [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js).

*edit* — note that by writing "just a wrapper" I do not mean to belittle the pjax plugin. I simply meant that it's not some radical new functionality; it's still XMLHttpRequest under the covers.

Comment: Can you give me some basic information or link about "pushState" and "popState" ? Thank you

Comment: [Here is the MDC page about `window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history)