# Will IE10 support the HTML 5 History API?

Tags: internet-explorer, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Internet Explorer support pushState and replaceState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722815/does-internet-explorer-support-pushstate-and-replacestate)

Any word yet on whether IE10 will support the HTML 5 History API?

Answer (score 5):

No, IE10 does not support HTML5 History API.

Check [IE10 Platform Preview 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ukmsdn/archive/2011/06/29/ie10-platform-preview-2-released.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

YESSS! Looks like IE10 will have it :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh272905.aspx#_HTML5History

Comment: as of today, it has a bug making it useless: **IE10 history implementation has a bug, the popstate event does not fire**. Here is the **test fiddle**, that works in chrome and firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/citykid/dFs6R/1/

Answer (score 0):

Check [Metro style browsing: one engine, two experiences, no compromises](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/14/metro-style-browsing-and-plug-in-free-html5.aspx) out. According to the blog, the feature should be available in the IE10 in the Win8 BUILD version already.