# I have broken my Rails 3.1 app for IE, jQuery events are not responding

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Only Internet Explorer is not working (I happen to be using version 8, but 7 and 9 are not working either). I have this code in my application.js file:

```
$(".attrs").live('click',function() {
    $("#product_application_" + $("#product_application_page_attribute").val()).val($(this).text());
    hash = { type: "POST", url: "brands/get_attributes", data: $("#attributeform").serialize() };
    $.bbq.pushState(hash);
    return false;
});
```

IE does NOTHING when I click on the elements that this event is bound to. What have I done?

Comment: Is there anything that appears in the developer's console?

Comment: check the console. you probably have a typo somewhere

Comment: might have something to do with pushState not supported on IE? (will be on IE 10 I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be due to the fact that pushState is not supported by IE8. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722815/does-internet-explorer-support-pushstate-and-replacestate).

Comment: That was definitely it. I had to put an explicit post in there. But now every other browser posts twice. I have to find a way to detect the browser.