# does html5 push state support in iPad and iPhones?

Tags: html

I want to use html5 Push state in my application but i have question does html 5 support iPhones, ipads and other mobile devices? if not then what is the alternative way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of html 5 supporting those devices, but the browsers used by those devices implementing html 5.

The "When Can I Use" website will be handy to you.  It will help you understand what features are available now.
http://caniuse.com/#search=push

Also, see this post: [Does Internet Explorer support pushState and replaceState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722815/does-internet-explorer-support-pushstate-and-replacestate)

It will give you some more information on what you can do to implement what you need.  One person made mention of history.js.  You may want to look into that as an alternative, if the features you seek are not available.