# IE8 JavaScript methods alternative

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am using below functions which are running perfectly fine with Chrome and Mozilla but not in Internet Explorer 8.

Below are the two function not supported by IE8 (I am putting whole function)

```
history.pushState(stateObj, "", "index.php?tabid=" + tab_id + "")},
```

For below it is giving error at if statement dont understand why..

```
var feeds = feedObj.responseData.feed.entries;
for (var i = 0; i < feeds.length && i < feed_entries; i++) {
    var feed = feeds[i];
    var thumb = "";
    var pubdate = new Date(feed.publishedDate);
    var delay = $app.gen.formatDelay($app.gen.delayFromNow(pubdate));
    if ("mediaGroups" in feed && Array.isArray(feed.mediaGroups)
            && "contents" in feed.mediaGroups[0]
            && Array.isArray(feed.mediaGroups[0].contents)
            && "url" in feed.mediaGroups[0].contents[0]
            && typeof feed.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].url != _indef)
        thumb = feed.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].url;
}
```

Any suggestion to change it so that it will work in all the browsers?

Thank you guys.

Comment: IE8 has no equivalent of the history API.

Comment: Nor `Array.isArray`.

Comment: Google for polyfills for the functions you're trying to use.

Comment: IE9 doesn't even support push state or pop state. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4968481/304832

Comment: Have you considered the history.js polyfill for earlier versions of IE? (https://github.com/browserstate/history.js)

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable suggestion. I am able to get Polyfills for array, history is not that important so just skipping it at this moment.