# Internet Explorer throwing SecurityError when I call window.history.pushState()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am getting "SecurityError" thrown when I call the History API in Internet Explorer and it won't continue running.

Here is the code:

```
if(window.history.pushState) {
        window.history.pushState({name: 'initial'}, 'initial', '');
}
```

That is right where it breaks and I can't figure out how to get around it, as Internet Explorer 10+ supports the history API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not every version of IE10 supports `pushState` http://stackoverflow.com/a/4968481/3592347

Comment: I'm even trying to use IE11 and the same thing is happening.

Comment: @tcase360 any solution ?