# Change URL without refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I would like to replace an url without page refresh.

I need to change:

```
https://example.com/en/step1
```

to

```
https://example.com/en/step2
```

How to do that ?

Comment: change the url of your address or on <a> link

Answer (score 122, accepted):

**Update**

Based on [Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), passing the empty string as second parameter of `pushState` method (*aka title*) should be safe against future changes to the method, so it's better to use `pushState` like this:

```
history.pushState(null, '', '/en/step2');
```

*You can read more about that in mentioned article*

**Original Answer**

Use `history.pushState` like this:

```
history.pushState(null, null, '/en/step2');
```

- More info (*MDN article*): [Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)
- [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history)
- Maybe you should take a look @ [Does Internet Explorer support pushState and replaceState?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3722815/3367974)

---

**Update 2** to answer **Idan Dagan**'s comment:

> Why not using `history.replaceState()`?

*From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)*

> history.replaceState() operates exactly like history.pushState() except that replaceState() modifies the current history entry instead of creating a new one

That means if you use `replaceState`, yes the url will be changed but user can not use Browser's Back button to back to prev. state(s) anymore (*because `replaceState` doesn't add new entry to history*) and it's not recommended and provide bad UX.

**Update 3** to add **`window.onpopstate`**

So, as this answer got your attention, here is additional info about manipulating the browser history, after using `pushState`, you can detect the back/forward button navigation by using `window.onpopstate` like this:

```
window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    // ... 
};
```

As the first argument of `pushState` is an object, if you passed an `object` instead of `null`, you can access that object in `onpopstate` which is very handy, here is how:

```
window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    if(e.state) {
        console.log(e.state);
    }
};
```

**Update 4** to add [Reading the current state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/step3#Reading_the_current_state):

When your page loads, it might have a non-null state object, you can read the state of the current history entry without waiting for a `popstate` event using the `history.state` property like this:

```
console.log(history.state);
```

**Bonus**: Use following to check `history.pushState` support:

```
if (history.pushState) {
  // \o/
}
```

Comment: Why not using history.replaceState()?

Comment: @IdanDagan I updated my answer to explain why. happy coding!

Comment: Note: if you are having trouble with a path being removed from the URL, remove the `/` at the start of the path that's in the code above

Answer (score 17):

When you use a function ...

```
<p onclick="update_url('/en/step2');">Link</p>

<script>
function update_url(url) {
    history.pushState(null, null, url);
}
</script>
```