# How can I change the URI without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, uri

I have built a website with CodeIginer and I want to implement AJAX and JQuery in one of my pages. The problem is that when I load the content, the URL does not change.

Let’s say that I have these URI:

- `http://www.example.com/controller/function/param`
- `http://www.example.com/controller/function/param2`

How can I change from the first one to the second one when I click a button?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In HTML5 you can change the URL:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

check http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState().c2.a0method

---

**UPDATE**

An overview of which browser support the new HTML5 history API:

http://caniuse.com/#search=pushState (caniuse.com is worth to bookmark!)

there are already frameworks that do the hard work for you and even gracefully fallback to the common hash-tag solution:

[**History.js**](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js)

> History.js gracefully supports the HTML5 History/State APIs
>   (pushState, replaceState, onPopState) in all browsers. Including
>   continued support for data, titles, replaceState. Supports jQuery,
>   MooTools and Prototype. For HTML5 browsers this means that you can
>   modify the URL directly, without needing to use hashes anymore. For
>   HTML4 browsers it will revert back to using the old onhashchange
>   functionality.

[**Backbone.js**](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)

> Backbone supplies structure to JavaScript-heavy applications by
>   providing models with key-value binding and custom events, collections
>   with a rich API of enumerable functions, views with declarative event
>   handling, and connects it all to your existing application over a
>   RESTful JSON interface.
>   ...
>   pushState support exists on a purely opt-in basis in Backbone. 
>   Older browsers that don't support pushState will continue to use 
>   hash-based URL fragments, and if a hash URL is visited by a 
>   pushState-capable browser, it will be transparently upgraded to the true URL.

[**Mootools** (via Plugin)](http://mootools.net/forge/p/history)

> MooTools is a compact, modular, Object-Oriented JavaScript framework designed for the intermediate to advanced JavaScript developer. [...] History Management via popstate or hashchange. Replaces the URL of the page without a reload and falls back to Hashchange on older
>   browsers.

[**dojo toolkit**](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/app.html)

> Dojo saves you time and scales with your development process, using web standards as 
>   its platform. It’s the toolkit experienced developers turn to for building high 
>   quality desktop and mobile web applications. [...] dojox.app manage the navigation 
>   history through HTML5 pushState standard and delegate it to browser enabled
>   history management.

... just to name a few.

---

**(!!) BE AWARE**

One **important side-effect** when using the `pushState` (citation from the [Backbone documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#History)):

> **Note that using real URLs requires your web server to be able to
>   correctly render those pages**, so back-end changes are required as
>   well. For example, if you have a route of /documents/100, your web
>   server must be able to serve that page, if the browser visits that URL
>   directly. For full search-engine crawlability, it's best to have the
>   server generate the complete HTML for the page ... but if it's a web
>   application, just rendering the same content you would have for the
>   root URL, and filling in the rest with Backbone Views and JavaScript
>   works fine.

Comment: Just so you know, with my experience with history.pushState, it does not gracefully degrade, and does not work in IE9, it actually broke my scripts. be sure to implement a fix, or use document.location.hash instead. you could use modernizer.js to detect whether the browser supports it.

Answer (score 9):

Could use a **hash** (**#**) and put whatever you like afterwards.

Here's a site I built using this - and then I have JavaScript read the hash and call appropriate functions:

http://bannerhouse.com.au/#/popup=media&id=don

**Side note:**

This is useful for flash websites or flash content as well; you can use FlashVars to parse the hash value to the SWF and load an appropriate section/screen based on that.

Answer (score 4):

Use hash tags via Javascript, so in the button's click event handler:
`location.hash = "param2"`
Which will change http://example.com/mypage/#whatever
to
http://example.com/mypage/#param2

Of course, you could also put your "folders" after the hash, so, with a base url of http://example.com/ you then add:
`location.hash = "/MyPage/MySubPage/MyInfo";`
which changes it to http://example.com/#/MyPage/MySubPage/MyInfo

Comment: when I tried that, the first url `http://www.example.com/controller/function/param` became `http://www.example.com/controller/function/param/#/controller/function/param2` and if I press enter on the URL, I got the same content with the first URL.. How do I change the content to the second one when I press the URL??

Answer (score 1):

A [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488165/javascript-changing-the-get-parameter-without-redirecting) deduced no, unless using a hash tag.

One idea put forward, but strongly discouraged, was using a 204 HTTP response.

From the W3:

> No Response 204
>
> Server has received the request but
> there is no information to send back,
> and the client should stay in the same
> document view. This is mainly to allow
> input for scripts without changing the
> document at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant excerpt from WHATWG’s HTML Living Standard (formerly known as HTML5), [§ 7.10.2 The session history of browsing contexts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-session-history-of-browsing-contexts):

> Several contiguous entries in a session history can share the same document. This can occur when the initial entry is reached via normal navigation, and the following entry is added via `history.pushState()`. Or it can occur via navigation to a fragment.