# deezer player and url changes without music stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, implementation, deezer

Have you ever used deezer.com? If you have and you are a developer you have questioned how can the music still play and the url of the page in the address bar is changing without hash , only reloading the content but the player not...

Like using 2 iframes and the parent page gets the url from the reloaded iframe page but not reloading the the second one or the whole site ?

If my description is not accurate, please ask me for more details.

Who know about this feature , or an example of how to do this ?

I have seen that is possible in browsers like ie10,ff,chrome , but on browsers like ie7-8, how can this be possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use the new HTML5 history api.

Some resources about it:

- [How can I change the page URL without refreshing the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118693/how-can-i-change-the-page-url-without-refreshing-the-page)
- http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

To check that Deezer does use this feature:

> wget http://cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/core.js -O - | grep 'history.pushState'