# keep header remain when navigating to different links of website

Tags: html, css

How do we keep the header remain there even when navigating to different links within a site?

ex flipkart.com, eemli.com - when you click the header links, the header gives a feeling that it remains but the page and URL changes. I understand if the header has dynammic ever-changing contents, this cannot be achieved.

Comment: i dont know how to approach this, one thing i learnt is that many such sites are using full URLs like eemli.com/page in href links but came across flipkart that doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good article showing some tecniques to achieve that...

[How can I change the page URL without refreshing the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118693/how-can-i-change-the-page-url-without-refreshing-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

Every page sends the same header, either through a templating system (JSP, Velocity, Freemarker, etc) or because it's hardcoded that way.  Each new page just renders the same HTML at the top of the page.

Comment: i am using asp.net master pages and every page renders the same header html everytime

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do one of two things.

1. Use a [frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame) to load your content (very old web technique), or
2. Load in the content of the next page with AJAX and replace what's underneath the header.

Of the two, #1 is more foolproof but #2 has a slicker feeling. That being said, I can't imagine using techniques like this are good for SEO.