# How to change my Url without reloading the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, url

Basically, when I click a link on my homepage, I want to use some JavaScript to slid in a new div and change the url so that if the url was typed, it would bring the right info. I dont want the entire page to load when a link is click. While surfing from link to link, I want to animate the webs change instead loading a new page.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways of achieving this:

**Using plain JavaScript in your anchors (DEFINITELY NOT RECOMMENDED)**
By doing this i mean literally do:

```
<a href="javascript:goToHome()">Home page</a>
```

You could do this, but this means you will be polluting the global scope with global variables and functions, which is strictly not recommended.

**Using the "#" in all your anchors**
This is the most common and safest way to do it, since is available in almost all major browsers and their different versions

```
<a href="#/home/">Home page</a>
```

The intention of the hash is to take you directly to a section within the document you are currently reading, that section is defined by the `id` attribute in HTML, this was intended for very large HTML documents. With the hash and the `window.onhashchange` event you can get what you want, except for some old versions of **IE** which i think are **7** and below.

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(event) {
    //your navigation logic here
});
```

More on `hashchange`: [onhashchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange)

**Using the `window.history` API**
This is the newest way to achieve it, since it's quite new not all browsers support it, but it's a nice way to do it:

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

Where:
*stateObj*: is an object that can be passed between history states.
*title*: Just a title for the new state.
*url*: The new URL to be displayed in the address bar.
This function call will trigger the `window.onpopstate` event on the browser.

More on History API:[HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
window.location.hash = "id of the element to be scrolled to";
```

You can use this code, which I've taken from [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

```
$(function () {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The above will automatically do the work for you.

[**Demo**](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with "old" browsers then window.location.hash is your only option, and this can't manipulate the whole URL, only manipulate for example #about to the end.

If you're willing to forgo old browsers then you can go window.history.pushState as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Here is an overview for browser compatibility with pushState: http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate

There's more information in this thread: [How can I change the page URL without refreshing the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118693/how-can-i-change-the-page-url-without-refreshing-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at ember.js.  It is a framework that does exactly what you're asking about (if I understood you correctly) and it handles all of the history for you.  There's a helpful tutorial on code school to get you going that walks you through building a simple bootstrap site at: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/warming-up-with-emberjs