# Is the anchor part of a URL being sent to a web server?

Tags: ajax, url, browser

Say, there's a URL, `http://www.example.com/#hello`.

1. Will the `#hello` thing be sent to the web server or not, according to standards?
2. How do modern browsers act?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer to this question is similar to the answers for *[Retrieving anchor link in URL for ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774136/retrieving-anchor-link-in-url-for-asp-net)*.

Basically, according to the standard at *[RFC 1808 - Relative Uniform Resource Locators](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1808.html)* (see Section 2.4.1), it says:

> "Note that the fragment identifier is not considered part of the URL."

As [*stephbu* pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774136/retrieving-anchor-link-in-url-for-asp-net/774270#774270), "the anchor tag is never sent as part of the HTTP request by any browser. It is only interpreted locally within the browser".

Answer (score 9):

The hash variables aren't sent to the web server at all.

For instance, a request to http://www.whatismyip.org/#test from Firefox sends the follow HTTP request packet

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.whatismyip.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

You'll notice the # is nowhere to be found.
Pages you see using # as a form of navigation are doing so through javascript.
This parameter is accessible though the `window.location.hash` variable

Comment: No browser that I am aware of transmits the `#hash` part of a URL to the server.

Answer (score 1):

The anchor part (after the #) is not sent to any $_SERVER variables in PHP. I don't know if there is a way of retrieving that piece of info from the URL or not (as far as I know, it's not possible). It's supposed to be used by the browser only to find a location in the page, which is why the page does not reload if you click on an anchor like so: `<a href="#hello">hello</a>`