# Rails request referrer doesn't contain the #xxx

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3 form where I'm using Bootstrap tabs.
Each tab renders a different form (but to the same controller).

When I submit the form on tab2, the URL at the top of the page is:

```
http://localhost:3000/costprojects/1#tab2
```

In the costprojects controller, I want to go to the next tab when the user submits a form.

I thought this would work:

```
  def update
    @costproject = Costproject.find(params[:id])
    nextpath =  costproject_path(@costproject) + '#tab2'
    nextpath =  costproject_path(@costproject) + '#tab3' if request.referer.include?("#tab2")
    nextpath =  costproject_path(@costproject) + '#tab4' if request.referer.include?("#tab3")


    respond_to do |format|
      if @costproject.update_attributes(params[:costproject])
        format.html { redirect_to nextpath, notice: 'Capital Project was successfully updated.' }
```

But, the `request.referer` doesn't include the 'tab2'.

How come?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Relying on referer isn't a good idea. Couldn't you provide a hidden field in the form and use that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor is only available client side.  It's never sent as part of any request header.  See [Is the anchor part of a URL being sent to a web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067491/is-the-anchor-part-of-a-url-being-sent-to-a-web-server)