# How can I use nginx rewrite with try_files to get react router working?

Tags: nginx, reactjs, react-router

I am using the try_files directive with nginx and react to force all paths to go to /index.html and be handled by the react router so that the paths don't need to be prefaced with /#/.

This works for that:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

So a url like `/invitation` will go to the right place.

However, there are still some sources that are generating `/#/` urls and I would like to have them rewritten to the equivalent urls without the `/#/` (so `/#/invitation` would go to `/invitation`).

I have tried every variation I can think of on this, including changing the order, escaping special characters, and with and without the permanent redirect, but nothing works:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/#/(.*) $1 permanent;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the section of a URL from the `#` onwards, is not actually sent to the server and is therefore not available for rewriting.

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten about that. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richard Smith's comment is correct - the anchor portion never gets sent to the server. More info here: [Is the anchor part of a URL being sent to a web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067491/is-the-anchor-part-of-a-url-being-sent-to-a-web-server)