# Getting a URL in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

In a Djano project, I need to get the complete URL of my web app in a view, along with the URL's anchor tag. For instance, if the URL is:

```
http://example.com/#section0
```

I need to get that in its entirely, including the `#section0` part. As you'd already know, `HTTP_REFERER` doesn't suffice (which is what I've tried).

What's a good way to read URLs in python/django? Beginner here, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but the anchor tag is never sent to the server. The only way a server could know what it was is if the server itself sent the user to a url with the anchor tag.
See here for more information:

[Is the anchor part of a URL being sent to a web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067491/is-the-anchor-part-of-a-url-being-sent-to-a-web-server)