# Get incoming URL from listening socket/HTTPServer

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, httpserver

Good day Stackoverflow,

This morning I've ran into a problem of which I can't seem to find a working answer. I'm trying to get the full URL (what shows up in the address bar) via either a `HTTPServer` or simple `socket`-ing that I get from a server that redirects me to `localhost` (Which has nothing behind it (no webserver, no pages, nothing), except the listening code below.) with the `token` and `scope` variables (as seen in the URL in question below). My desired result would be these variables to be saved so I can work with them:
`http://localhost/#token=aai789as&scope=book%3Aedit+chat%3Aedit`

I have tried the following with some progress but not the desired result:

```
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        qs = {}
        path = self.path
        if '?' in path:
            path, tmp = path.split('?', 1)
            qs = urlparse.parse_qs(tmp)

        print(self.path)
        print (path, qs)

    def log_request(self, code=None, size=None):
        print('Request')

    def log_message(self, format, *args):
        print('Message')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(('localhost', 80), MyHandler)
        print('Started http server')
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('^C received, shutting down server')
        server.socket.close()
```

The above snippet loads, but doesn't actually print anything of use. In fact, it prints just blank statements. But it does detect a connection being made.
So does this:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("localhost", 80))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
d = conn.recv(4096)
conn.close()

print(d)
```

But this DOES return more than blank statements, yet it's hardly enough to get the variables from the URL:

```
b'\x07\n'
b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.7,nl;q=0.3\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nDNT: 1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n\r\n'
```

I don't know what I'm supposed to be doing and since I don't know what exactly I'm looking for; searching through the documentation has taken up the better half of my day. As such I turn to the ever helpful Stackoverflow in the hopes of finding better knowledge than I possess.

Thank you for your time,
- Brent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 http://localhost/#token=aai789as&scope=book%3Aedit+chat%3Aedit
```

This kind of URL is only transferred in part to the server. The `#` and everything after is only known to the browser and can be accessed as `location.hash` from withing Javascript. It will not be transferred to the server, i.e. all the server will see is `http://localhost/`.

```
b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\n ...'
```

This part provides everything from the URL which the server will know. The `localhost` in the `Host` header specifies the hostname and the `GET /` specifies the path `/` - which makes together `'http://' + 'localhost' + '/'` i.e. `http://localhost/`.

For more information see [Is the anchor part of a URL being sent to a web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067491/is-the-anchor-part-of-a-url-being-sent-to-a-web-server).