# In Spring Boot, can we pass anchor tag, as a variable, through URL like @PathVariable or @RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I would like to use URL http://localhost:8080/blog#section & obtain #section as a variable in getBlog() method.

```
// localhost:8080/blog#section
@GetMapping("/blog/{section}")
public String getBlog(Model model, @PathVariable("section") String section){
    return "blog" + section; // localhost:8080/blog#section
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The **#section** part is never sent to server ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067491/is-the-anchor-part-of-a-url-being-sent-to-a-web-server)),so what you are demanding is impossible.

In fact **#section** is used for browser to locate the content of a web page, it's not used for server to decide which content to return.

What you are demanding can be easyily achieved with a query like `localhost:8080/blog?section=?` or a url path like `localhost:8080/blog/section`