# Get anchor tag from Django request URL

Tags: python, django

I have a Django template filter where I'm trying to check the request URL to see whether it includes an anchor tag or not.

For example, I want to check if the request URL is:

`/mypath/mypage/my-slug/` or `/mypath/mypage/my-slug/#myanchor`

If it is the latter, I want to get the anchor tag ID.

Currently, the anchor tag seems to be stripped from the request information: `request.path`, `request.build_absolute_uri()` and so on. I can only get `/mypath/mypage/my-slug/`.

The URL pattern for the page in question is:

```
re_path(r'^(?P<product_slug>[\w-]*)_(?P<pk>\d+)/$', self.detail_view.as_view(), name='detail')
```

I can see the regex looks for the line end after the last slash, which suggests the anchor is being excluded, but I can easily retrieve `GET` params from the URL and I expected this to be straightforward too. It feels like I am missing something pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section tag is not sent to the server, but interpreted by the browser :
[Is the anchor part of a URL being sent to a web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067491/is-the-anchor-part-of-a-url-being-sent-to-a-web-server)

Now, if you need to the anchor ID, you will have to do so using AJAX and write your own view to receive the data.

Comment: Pretty much what I assumed. Thanks.