# How to read query parameter after (hash)#

Tags: django, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

Here I have Url
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/#access_token=ya29.a0AVA9y1tO4d94lkiHbIT2qjh89k0TNGXFMJ_6XzdHXvxLrsLbphuMaBmEvUHCSX8XWq5L3dqQ88ULG9Vsw1llmYi24DpbFamGcoW4KPZP-9y2ynPBJMqmuFdazz7t9KEp5qrdkVwvaCgYKATASAQASFQE65dr8nbFmeih28Lvt_Q68CBXhiQ0163

I want to get value of access_token and return that token as response mention below
but don't know the way to get query_parameter after hash(#)

```
{
"token":'ya29.a0AVA9y1tO4d94lkiHbIT2qjh89k0TNGXFMJ_6XzdHXvxLrsLbphuMaBmEvUHCSX8XWq5L3dqQ88ULG9Vsw1llmYi24DpbFamGcoW4KPZP-9y2ynPBJMqmuFdazz7t9KEp5qrdkVwvaCgYKATASAQASFQE65dr8nbFmeih28Lvt_Q68CBXhiQ0163'
}
```

in urls.py

```
from user.views import GoogleRedirect
 path('accounts/google/login/callback/', GoogleRedirect.as_view())
```

in views.py

```
class GoogleRedirect(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        return Response("success")
```

Comment: The fragment is *not* send to the server...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the anchor part of a URL being sent to a web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067491/is-the-anchor-part-of-a-url-being-sent-to-a-web-server)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is this a good idea but if you really want to do this:

```
  $.get(`{% url "grv" %}${window.location.hash.slice(1)}`, function(data, status){
    console.log('done')
  });
// be sure that URL has a slash at the end (grv)
```

urls.py

```
from user.views import GoogleRedirect
...
 path('accounts/google/login/callback/<str:token>', GoogleRedirect.as_view(), name="grv")
...
```

views.py

```
class GoogleRedirect(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        return JsonResponse({"token" : self.kwargs['token']})
```