# How to get the anchor of url in play's controller

Tags: url, playframework

Suppose I have a controller and an action:

```
public Questions extends BaseController {
    public static void show(id) {
        // how to get the anchor here??
    }
}
```

A url with anchor like `http://aaa.com/questions/show?id=123#555` will map to this action, and how can we get the anchor `555` in action `show`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it is not possible to send the anchor part of a url back to the server as part of the http request. It is used locally only, for anchoring a page for intra page navigation.

See this post for more info [Retrieving Anchor Link In URL for ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774136/retrieving-anchor-link-in-url-for-asp-net)

However, if you want to add the anchor in your view, rather than using redirects and using the router in the controller, you can simply do it in the view (where it best belongs)

```
<a href='@{Questions.show(id)}#555'>link to question</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

To add anchor to url, i use redirect method and Router class, so for your case :

```
public Questions extends BaseController {
    public static void show(id) {

        some stuff...

        Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        args.put("id", questionID);
        String url = Router.getFullUrl("Questions.show", args);
        redirect(url + "#555");
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe `Router.reverse("Questions.show", args).addRef("555")` is better :)