# Redirect with anchor in play 2

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm looking for possibility to add anchor to url returned in controller:

```
public static Result open(String id) {
  // here I want to add acnhor like #foo to the produced url
  return redirect(routes.MyPage.show(id));
}
```

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699180/how-to-get-the-anchor-of-url-in-plays-controller/4699764#comment5186899_4699764) that it was possible in play 1 using `addRef` method, but I couldn't find any replacement of the method in play 2.

Of course I can use concatenation like:

```
public static Result open(String id) {
  // here I want to add acnhor like #foo to the produced url
  return redirect(routes.MyPage.show(id).url + "#foo");
}
```

But it seems ugly.

Thank you for any help! Have a good day!

Comment: I think it's currently not possible.

Comment: What's wrong with your example?

Comment: @i.am.michiel I don't like string concatenation: what if this method will be called thousands of times. BTW, if I will use `String.format` is it will be faster?

Comment: @i.am.michiel you're right nothing wrong, my guess is simply that the use case it-self is a bit weird. That's probably why grigory doesn't feel statisfied...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before trying to answer that question.
I should recommend you change whatever behavior you're currently setting.

Because, an URL fragment's purpose is client side only. Such fragment is never sent to the server, so that it's cumbersome to do the opposite.

However, here is the embryo of a (quite?) elegant solution that you could follow.

What I'll try to do is to leave the browser deal with the fragment, in order to keep potential behaviors (f.i. go to ID or even deal with history...).

To do so, you could add an `implicit` parameter to your `main` template which will define the fragment that the URL should have:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)(urlFragment:Option[UrlFragment] = None)
```

As you can see I wrapped the parameter in an `Option` and default'ed it to `None` (in order to avoid AMAP pollution).

Also, it simply wraps a `String` but you could use `String` alone -- using a dedicated type will enforce the semantic. Here is the definition:

```
case class UrlFragment(hash:String)
```

Very simple.

Now here is how to tell the browser to deal with it. Right before the end of the `head` element, and the start of `body`, just add the following:

```
@urlFragment.map { f =>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      //after everything is ready, so that other mechanism will be able to use the change hash event...
      document.location.hash = "@Html(@f.hash)";
    });
  </script>
}
```

As you can see, using `map` (that is when the `urlFragment` is not `None`) we add a script block that will set the hash available in `urlFragment`.

This might be a start, however... Think about another solution for the whole scenario.

Comment: Note that, for redirect since you don't call the template directly, you'll have to find a way to keep the hash. A flashed attribute should do the trick

Comment: Thank you! I get that whole scenario is kind of weird.

Comment: Actually, I'm just wondering which scenario it is. In factn it could make sense, but since I don't have information about it, it's not easy to figure out. If you give me more info, maybe playframework could have another feature that might help? hth

Comment: This might be useful when you use backend permalinks (not hash based) but your frontend app is using a different, hash-based routing logic (not all browsers support HTML5 history). Don't forget to espace the hash, we had a bug about this :) `document.location.hash = "@Html(routingHash)";`

Answer (score 3):

As of Play 2.4, it's possible to use [`Call.withFragment()`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/play/mvc/Call.html).

```
routes.Application.index.withFragment("some-id").absoluteURL(request)
```

This was added by [PR #4152](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/4152).