# How to get # value in query string from a URL coming from an API, not the current request

Tags: asp.net

I get a returned url from using facebook api:

http://www.example.com/#access_token=BAAGgUj7asdasdasdasda4z3cBAFD5ZAyTOMIxtBpjIHsNwLfZC6L9gZAIdSIt3bKP96rg7yAlplMBDA9ZCndAKS9a7m4oRmRmJAxSdCueefweWJrlq3vQv3XaGqTOLofEMjJIVNCYZD&expires_in=0

But i am not sure how to get the token value? As its not in query string or Request.url

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, assuming this is passed in on the current request, as anything after the `#` is never sent to the server.

You can capture it in JavaScript and use AJAX to send it to the server, but this will be on a different request.

---

If you mean you have this URL not from the current request, you can use the `Uri` class to parse a full URL and get the fragment:

```
var fragment = new Uri(theUri).Fragment;
var token = fragment.Split(new [] {'&','='}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
```

Comment: This still requires further processing, the `Fragment` property will return *everything* after the `#` so the OP would still need to parse the string. I do think the preferred method for this sort of scenario is to use `ParseQueryString`.

Comment: Yeah i think javascript and ajax is the straight way!

Comment: @Thank you for the idea i used javascript and ajax to get it done!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms150046.aspx) to parse the URL then you can get the value by name e.g.

```
NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);
string token = query["token"];
```

Comment: How does that work on the server side? For a value after the `#`?

Comment: The OP states the URL is *returned* from the an api server, it doesn't mention anything about that URL being the current request.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Retrieving Anchor Link In URL for ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774136/retrieving-anchor-link-in-url-for-asp-net)

you cannot get it from the server side, you will need to take if from client side first then pass it to the server in a hidden field or something similar

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for "%23", because "#" is url-encoded to "%23"

reference: 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

But you have to know also, that anchors are not available on server side!