# How do I redirect to an anchor tag on my aspx page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, anchor

I tried `Response.Redirect("page.aspx#here")` but it did not work.

This is the code in my aspx file: `<a name="here"></a>` Do I have to redirect to it differently?

Comment: In html (or Razor) that would be <a id="here"></a> .. which works for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't redirect to an anchor from server-side code, because the anchor is entirely a client-side concept. You'll have to use Javascript for this. See [Retrieving Anchor Link In URL for ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774136/retrieving-anchor-link-in-url-for-asp-net).

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer here is incorrect.

I am able to make this work in C# by doing the following:

```
Response.Redirect("page.aspx" + "#here", false);
```

Comment: It seems like the accepted answer adequately answers the question.  In what way is it incorrect to say the anchor tag is a client-side function?

Comment: He said it isn't possible, that's incorrect. It's true that its client side, but can be passed to another page using response.redirect, which he says isn't possible.