# Getting the request URL with hash #content in Helidon SE

Tags: helidon

I am writing a Helidon SE webserver and I am not to process the #content as part of URL.

I tried the following:
`ServerRequest request;`
`request.uri()`
`request.absoluteUri()`
None of them is giving me the hash content of the request URL.
For example: `https://example.com/#code=xyz` I need to extract 'xyz'

Answer (score 1):

The anchor is not sent to the server by the client (e.g. browser / curl).

```
curl -vvv http://localhost:8080/foo\?bob\=alice\#xyz
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /foo?bob=alice HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
```

See this answer which goes into more details.
[Retrieving anchor link in URL for ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774136/retrieving-anchor-link-in-url-for-asp-net/774270#774270)